# Applying the Kelly Criterion in a joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gambling

The simpler case I am considering is when we have two bets, A and B, where the value after taking a turn after each bet is described as the following:
\begin{equation}
  F_{A}(f_{A}) =
    \begin{cases}
      1+u_{A}f_{A} & \text{with the probability $p_{A}$}\\
      1-d_{A}f_{A} & \text{with the probability $1-p_{A}$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  F_{B}(f_{B}) =
    \begin{cases}
      1+u_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $p_{B}$}\\
      1-d_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $1-p_{B}$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Where $f$ is a fraction of your total asset, $a$ and $b$ are the return on the bet for a succesful and unsuccessful bet.

By the kelly criterion, when only considering bet A, the optimum fraction f is the following, where

\begin{equation}
f = \dfrac{p_A}{d_A} - \dfrac{1-p_A}{u_A}      
\end{equation}

When taking into consideration of both bets, and under the assumption that they are independent, we have
\begin{equation}
  F_{A, B}(f_{A}, f_{B}) =
    \begin{cases}
      1+u_{A}f_{A}+u_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $p_{A}p_{B}$}\\
      1+u_{A}f_{A}-d_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $p_{A}(1-p_{B})$}\\
      1-d_{A}f_{A}+u_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $(1-p_{A})p_{B}$}\\
      1-d_{A}f_{A}-d_{B}f_{B} & \text{with the probability $(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B})$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

From what I understand, I can take $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\ln((F(f_{A}, f_{B})))$ and take partial derivative w.r.t. $f_{A}$ and $f_{B}$ and find the pair $(f_{A}, f_{B})$ to maximize the expected return.

However, How do I find the pair $(f_{A}, f_{B})$ when the two bets are not independent? That is, how do I modify the equation to take into account the correlation between $F_{A}(f_{A})$ and $F_{B}(f_{B})$?

Furthermore, generalizing this situation to when we have the return of the bets to be a continuous random variable, where $P(X_{i}) = P_{i}$, with the value comming out of each turn in the bet as $1+fX_{i}$, what is the equivalent kelly fraction pair $(f_{A}, f_{B})$?

Comment: Doesn't the Kelly-optimal bet maximize $\mathbb{E}(log(F(f_A,f_B)))$ not the expected value? The first order approach of taking partial derivatives doesn't assume independence so you can still use that.

Comment: Sorry typed it wrong. The first approach makes assumptions on the probability of $F_{A,B}(f_{A}, f_{B})$, because when bet A and B are not independent, the probability of having bet A and B both successful $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A) \cdot P(B)$

Comment: Yes but you can just modify the probabilities.

Comment: Sorry but that is kind of where I'm stuck at. I'm not sure how to incorporate correlation and covariance into the probabilities.